# AngularJS custom $http service with auto retry feature

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to do a custom $http service that will automatically retry fail connection. My code look something like this:

```
angular.factory('myHttp', service);

function service($http){
    var obj = {};
    obj.get = function(path) {
       return $http.get(path).then(function(result){
            return result;
       },function(result){
                obj.get(path);
       });
     }
    return obj;
}
```

When using it, it will be use normally almost like using `$http`. For example:

```
    myHttp.get($scope.url).
      then(function(response) {
        console.log("It's success");
        $scope.status = response.status;
        $scope.data = response.data;
      });
```

It works if the connection is success. However, if connection fail it still return respond without data that console log will display `Error: response is undefined`. Then, the retry will become meaningless.

How can I have the service that will do retry connection when fail?

Comment: you can set failure counter where you will can set counter and the in it tell you that it tried maximum attempt

Answer (score 0):

Instead of call on service when failed do it where you call service

```
function doIt() {
    myHttp.get($scope.url).
    then(function (response) {
        console.log("It's success");
        $scope.status = response.status;
        $scope.data = response.data;
    }, function () {
        doIt();
    });
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it on service? If do with your suggestion, then why would I need my own custom service? The reason I am doing this is to have something reusable throughout my application.